# Eficiência em querys com schemas diferentes [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Existe alguma perda de eficiência fazendo querys em schemas diferentes?

Por exemplo a query 1 é mais eficiente do que a query 2?

```
1: SELECT * FROM SC1.T1 INNER JOIN SC1.T2 ON ...

2: SELECT * FROM SC1.T1 INNER JOIN SC2.T2 ON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independe, O que realmente precisa ser levado em consideração são os índices, então sempre no JOIN vc precisa usar indices para fazer a busca isso sim vai trazer eficiência e robustez a sua query!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Aloiso!